# How are notifications persisted and managed

Tags: discussion

I was just having a look the stackoverflow database schema from [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) as well as the list of technologies used for the network
[Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I assumed that notifications would have been stored in the database, but realised there is no notification table.

Does anyone have any insight into the internals of how the stackoverflow notification system works and how notifications are persisted?

Comment: The database dump **doesn't contain everything**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...the schema documentation **for the public data dump.** That's not the same as the production database that's used to run SE. You also won't find user authentication tokens and a bunch of other stuff that's irrelevant to the public data dump in there. The data dump contains all user supplied content, it's not a snapshot of the entire database.